# Is SQL Track Changes overkill to monitor data updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2017:

My local database gets push updates to tables when a specific column(or two) of a table gets updated, I want to get notified and be able to grab that specific row's data for use/consumption.

I am a novice in SQL code - I have done some reading on Track Changes in SQL, but is that overkill for such a simple task?  Speed is key.

EDIT:
I am using SQL Server Express - CDC not supported...

I will be using C# to call procedures.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using, I don't want to assume Sql-Server 2017 just because of the version of your management studio? Second, depending on your needs, as the first answer said, you can use triggers to track specific changes and even store the original data or a combination in a new table. You can then choose how long to store the data.

Comment: Only you will be able to determine whether *any* solution is *fast enough*.

Comment: If performance is required, I would consider CDC and avoid triggers as much as possible.

Comment: @SteveB:  Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as fast as I can get is fast enough!

Comment: @Andrew as I understand, CDC is asynchronous, change tracking is more "lightweight", thus faster? and synchronous..

Comment: @Allstar - synchronous should not be equated to faster - quite the opposite. Sync has a direct impact on your performance since it is inline with the changes. Async CDC has a latency, but works off the transaction log, and does not add additional time to DML statements changing the rows. Business requirements / SLA's and other NFRs drive the decision however.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I omitted to note I am using express edition so seems I have to go with change tracking, and avoid triggers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triggers for that purpose, but take into account that they can degrade the performance on the table.

Comment: . . Are you implying that the track changes functionality does not degrade performance?